# Passing result values from one PHP page to another

Tags: php

I've a form in which I send the values to be calculated to another PHP page which should do the calculation and return the values to this form page. If there is an error, it should return the error to this main page. How would I do that?

This is the basic form page: index.php:

```
<form id="deps" name="deps" action="calc.php" method="POST"> 
                <div id="er"> <span class="er" >&nbsp;</span></div>           
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="field head">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td class="field cv"><label for="met">Metric</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="field head"><label for="bd">Bore Dia.</label></td>
                        <td class="field"><input type="text" name="bdmm" id="bdmm" /><label for="bdmm">MM</label></td>
                        <tr>
                    <td class="field head"><label for="tw">Total Weight</label></td>
                    <td class="field"><input type="text" name="twkg" id="twkg" /> <label for="twkg">KG</label></td>

                </tr>
                    </tr>

                 </table>   
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Calculate" />                
              </form>


         </div>
```

Calc.php

```
<?php

$bdmm = $_POST['bdmm']; 


if(!$bdmm){ 
          $error = "Please enter a value!";
          echo $error;
     }  
    else {
        echo $bdmm ." success"; 
}
?>
```

If there is an error it should display the error in the `span` tag. And if there is no error and it calculates, it should return the result and display it in the `textbox`.

Is this possible without Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

**index.php:**

```
<?php
    $err = (isset($_GET['error'])) ? $_GET['error'] : '&nbsp;';
?>
<form id="deps" name="deps" action="calc.php" method="POST"> 
    <div id="er"> <span class="er" ><?php echo $err; ?></span></div>  
    ....rest of form
```

**calc.php:**

```
if(empty($_POST['bdmm'])){ 
    header('Location: index.php?error=Please enter a value!');
    exit();
}  
else {
    echo $_POST['bdmm'] ." success"; 
}
```

While this works just fine, I'd recommend you simply post the form to the same page and avoid the url redirection. If you use an MVC framework such as CodeIgniter or Zend, you can take advantage of unique urls within the same file and tell the controller to load the appropriate view while keeping the request on the same file.

Comment: Thank you. While this works quite well, I would not like to show this in the url: `?error=Please enter a value!`. Is there anyway to do that? And secondly, I'm assuming this won't work without url redirection unless I post the form to the same page as you said?

Comment: Correct, you can not redirect via `POST` so it will need to be in the URI unless you post to the same page.